# Is there an equivalent to String.Split that returns a generic list?

Tags: vb.net, generics

I'd like to do something like this:

```
Dim Foo as String = "a,b,c,d,e"
Dim Boo as List(of String) = Foo.Split(","c)
```

Of course `Foo.Split` returns a one-dimensional array of `String`, not a generic `List`. Is there a way to do this without iterating through the array to turn it into a generic `List`?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

If you don't want to use LINQ, you can do:

```
Dim foo As String = "a,b,c,d,e"
Dim boo As New List(Of String)(foo.Split(","c))
```

Comment: Did not know about the `c` for making a string a character... I've always used `new Char() { "," }` instead.  That's a **lot* neater

Answer (score 7):

You can use the List's constructor.

```
String foo = "a,b,c,d,e";
List<String> boo = new List<String>(foo.Split(","));
```

Comment: Sorry mats! No hard feelings!

Answer (score 6):

Do you really need a List<T> or will IList<T> do? Because string[] already implements the latter... just another reason why it's worth programming to the interfaces where you can. (It could be that in this case you really can't, admittedly.)

Comment: You can use IList<T>, in fact you should (even though I forgot to in my answer's code example)

Comment: I agree, although I am trying to get into this habbit.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest method would probably be the AddRange method.

```
Dim Foo as String = "a,b,c,d,e"
Dim Boo as List(of String)

Boo.AddRange(Foo.Split(","c))
```

Comment: Thanks - this works as well as the accepted answer but is slightly less compact.

Comment: That code works?  It looks to me like it would throw a NullReferenceException.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Linq, you can use the ToList() extension method

```
Dim strings As List<string> = string_variable.Split().ToList<string>();
```

Comment: How exactly do you propose using Linq to query a comma-separated string?

Comment: He's not querying it.  The ToList() extension method Code Monkey shows in his answer is just part of the class of functionality common known as "Linq" (and is used to support LINQ query, but you can use it for other things)

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I am doing it ... since the split is looking for an array of char I clip off the first value in my string.

```
var values = labels.Split(" "[0]).ToList<string>();
```

Answer (score 0):

To build on the answer, Ive found the following very helpful:

```
Return New List(Of String)(IO.File.ReadAllLines(sFileName))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim Foo as String = "a,b,c,d,e"
Dim Boo as List(of String)
Boo = Split(Foo, ",").ToList
```

The advantage of doing it this way is that the split-string will accept multiple characters:

```
Dim Foo as String = "a<blah>b<blah>c<blah>d<blah>e"
Dim Boo as List(of String)
Boo = Split(Foo, "<blah>").ToList
```